# Reverse ssh tunnel in config

Tags: ssh, configuration, ssh-tunneling

How can I establish a reverse ssh tunnel with my ./ssh/config file?

I'm trying to reproduce this command

```
ssh -R 55555:localhost:22 user@host
```

in my .ssh/config file so that when I type `ssh host` I'll ssh to the host as user and with a reverse tunnel. The commands accepted by the config file are more verbose counterparts to the command line flags. Based on the ssh manpage and the manpage for ssh_config, it seems like the corresponding setting is BindAddress.

In my .ssh/config file I have:

```
Host host
     Hostname host
     User user
     BindAddress 55555:localhost:22
```

This, and slight variations of, result in a connection refused when I try

```
ssh localhost -p 55555
```

once logged in on the host. The same works fine if I explicitly give the command at the top when first sshing to the host. My config file does work without the reverse tunnel command; `ssh host` logs me into host as user.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`BindAddress` is not the option you're after. From [`man ssh_config`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en):

```
BindAddress
         Use the specified address on the local machine as the source
         address of the connection.  Only useful on systems with more than
         one address.
```

The configuration file equivalent of `-R` is `RemoteForward`:

```
RemoteForward
         Specifies that a TCP port on the remote machine be forwarded over
         the secure channel to the specified host and port from the local
         machine.  The first argument must be [bind_address:]port and the
         second argument must be host:hostport. [...]
```

With this information the command line

```
ssh -R 55555:localhost:22 user@host
```

translates into the following `.ssh/config` syntax:

```
Host host
HostName host
User user
RemoteForward 55555 localhost:22
```

Comment: This question should be the poster child for the stackexchange Q&A format.